# $scope variable in HTML disappearing on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a scope variable that appears properly as it should when coming from somewhere else on the site. However, if the html page where the $scope variable is called from is refreshed, the variable value disappears.

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('testApp')
 .controller('TestShowCtrl', function($scope, Ref, $routeParams) {
    //Get ID out of current URL
    var currentId = $routeParams.id;

    var ref = new Firebase(Ref + 'events').child(currentId);

    ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val();
        console.log('data.title: ' + data.title);
        $scope.title = data.title;

    });
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<h3 id="test">Title: {{title}}</h3>
```

Strangely, while the HTML does not display the variable, it still appears in the console after refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronizing data from Firebase is an asynchronous operation. By the time the data comes back from Firebase and you bind it to the scope, AngularJS is not expecting changes anymore. So it doesn't immediately update the UI, but instead does so on the next "refresh cycle".

To trigger an immediate update, call `$timeout()` or `$apply()`:

```
angular.module('testApp')
 .controller('TestShowCtrl', function($scope, Ref, $routeParams, $timeout) {
    //Get ID out of current URL
    var currentId = $routeParams.id;

    var ref = new Firebase(Ref + 'events').child(currentId);

    ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { $timeout(function() {
        var data = snapshot.val();
        console.log('data.title: ' + data.title);
        $scope.title = data.title;
    })});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation along with the answer. That worked. I also needed **$timeout** added as a dependency on this line: .`controller('MemoryShowCtrl', function($scope, Ref, $routeParams, $timeout) {`